# Cargar datos de una tabla en un array

Tags: php, array, arraylist, object

La cosa es que tengo un bascador y el array lo tengo definido manualmente.

```
var links = {
            "http://localhost/":"FRIENDS",
            "http://localhost/":"BREAKING BAD",

        };
```

Y luego mediante otra función mientras escribe va mostrando el nombre. Lo que quiero hacer es que a través de una tabla en la bd que tendría como campos: enlace y nombre_serie cargar esos datos en el array links{}. Alguna idea?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. Además los array no se declaran con `{}`, sino con `[]` Puedes mejorar la pregunta pulsando en [edit]

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar realizar la conexión con la base de datos y hacer una consulta para recoger los datos de la siguiente manera:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$table = "table_series";

$links = [];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT enlace, nombre_serie FROM " . $table;
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //Creamos array con los datos
        $fila = array($row["enlace"]=>$row["nombre_serie"]);

        //Almacenamos los datos en el array original
        array_push($links, $fila);
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Hecho esto ya se debería haber generado en $links tu array con los contenidos de la base de datos. Solo tendrías que reemplazar las variables de la zona superior del código por los tuyos.

Comment: Vele gracias, lo pruebo y te digo.

Comment: Eso está perfecto , pero a la hora de incluir el php me da errores. function autocompletado() {
    
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = '';
   
 <?php 
include_once('buscador.php');
 ?>

Comment: Me sale que $links no está definido

Comment: cuando haces `$links = [];` lo estás definiendo e inicializando